# Add syntax highlighting language code lang-r to [data.table]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, documentation, syntax-highlighting

This post title follows the pattern of [another FR from earlier this year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321824) that was successful. Data.table is an R library and its docs would benefit from R syntax highlighting. Let me know if any more info is needed.

Now that docs are here and [we want many libraries' docs to live separately from their parent languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329707/), I guess there will be a lot of requests like this. For reference, here are all the [supported language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109).

While you're at it, there are several other R libraries that have tags likely to get their own docs (dplyr, ggplot2, ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been completed.  I've set the syntax highlighting for [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table), [dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dplyr), and [ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2) to be lang-r.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this. What would be the strategy to get syntax highlighting for other R packages? Specifically I'm interested in getting the tags [spatstat], [maptools] and [sp] to use lang-r for highlighting, but as the OP mentions there are probably many more packages where correct highlighting would be helpful. Should I open a new question whenever I see these or simply comment on this question? Or something else?

Comment: @EgeRubak Your best option would be to post a question asking for it, then the community can also weigh in and we'd have a record of why it was done.

Comment: OK @bluefeet I have now posted a new question to get syntax highlighting for these R packages: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336031/3341769

Comment: @bluefeet Is the same done for libraries in other languages? At any rate, as  an R contributor on this website I’d prefer if people actually tagged their questions as [tag:r]. I don’t see any value in adding syntax highlighting synonyms for package names.

Comment: @bluefeet If this is important for Documentation, maybe a system similar to synonym suggestion should be added?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Is it done on other libraries? I'm not sure.  This seemed like a reasonable request that would provide valid syntax highlighting when the r tag is not added.

Comment: [tag:data.table] is used for both python and R, so it can and will cause problems.

Comment: And yet @Braiam only [3 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table%20not%20r?mode=all) aren't tagged with R. And none are tagged with data.table and python without R.   But if it is a problem it can be undone.

Comment: Sorry it was the [tag:dataframe], which [was supposed to be merged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319591/792066)... mm.. still, I support @KonradRudolph point.

Comment: Ahh easy mistake @Braiam